# How to make it so a link will target a specific slide in the slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i make it so that when i click a link itll lead to me a certain div on my slideshow. Thanks

```
  <script>
      function Divs() {
          var divs= $('#parent div'),
              now = divs.filter(':visible'),
              next = now.next().length ? now.next() : divs.first(),
              speed = 1000
          now.fadeOut(speed);
          next.fadeIn(speed);
      }
    var timesClicked = 0;
    i = setInterval(Divs, 4000);
    $(".slideshow-container").click(function() {
      timesClicked += 1;
      if (timesClicked%2==0) {
        i = setInterval(Divs, 3000);
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(i)
    }
    })
    </script>
    <div class ='box' id = 'food'>
```

Comment: Post your code till a fully functional slideshow can be seen.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask